# In the context of date formatting, why does `%b` indicate abbreviated month?

Tags: date, format

When formatting dates, the use of `%m=month`, `%y=day`, and `%d=day` are obvious and memorable, but **what does the `b` in `%b` stand for?**

In other words, why does `%b` indicate abbreviated month? Is this simply working through alphabet to describe the various terms or is there a meaningful link?

I found plenty of sites that describe the format ([e.g. W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp), but I haven't been able to find the etymology of the `%b` term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a semantic rationale or mnemonic when there is none. Lower case b was probably chosen for symmetry with A, a for weekday and abbreviated weekday.
B and b provide the same for month names.

Answer (score 3):

In date formatting, %m is used for minutes; therefore, it cannot be used for month.

I don't think that the 'b' in %b stands for anything in particular. It was likely the first available single character value in the alphabet to represent the month.